# Objective C to C# (Image Cropping Code)

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I have a requirment to allow a photo to be cropped. for all tense and purposes its to do some image processing, with the result being as if the photo was scanned.

The photos will be of documents, and will be large images (iPad, iPad Mini)

I have built the code to do the processing with the help from the CoreImage lib, but I'm stuck on cropping the photo.

After browsing I have found some code that I have partially implemented in C# (monotouch)
Scrollview with content size matching the size of the photo, a UIimageView in side the scrollview (natarlly extending beyond the bounds of screen) , a fixed black semi-transparent view on-top of the scrollview.

My scrolling, zooming is all working great, but...

How do i "cut out" the cropping guide from my Black transparent view (cropGuideView) i am trying to cut out a scaled down A4 guide.

the code below seem to be what i need, but I am struggling to convert it to monotouch.

Thanks

```
CGRect cropGuide = self.cropGuideView.visibleRect;
UIEdgeInsets edges = self.cropGuideView.edgeWidths;
CGPoint cropGuideOffset = self.cropScrollView.contentOffset;

CGPoint origin = CGPointMake( cropGuideOffset.x + edges.left, cropGuideOffset.y + edges.top );
CGSize size = cropGuide.size;
CGRect crop = { origin, size };

crop.origin.x = crop.origin.x / self.cropScrollView.zoomScale;
crop.origin.y = crop.origin.y / self.cropScrollView.zoomScale;
crop.size.width = crop.size.width / self.cropScrollView.zoomScale;
crop.size.height = crop.size.height / self.cropScrollView.zoomScale;

photo = [photo croppedImage:crop];
```

Comment: Where are you struggling, exactly, and why? I don't know Objective C, but your snippet looks like 90% valid C# code. Just add a "new" when creating objects and convert the method call, and you should be done. Else, please let us know where you hit problems.

Comment: Hi Jeyk, The specifics are setting the visibleRect & edgeWidths in my cropping view. i believe once i have them i can continue, but there are no properties in my view that allows me to do that... at least thats what i think my problem is.

Answer (score 1):

Try this (from the [Xamarin forums](http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/14269/objective-c-image-crop-function))

```
UIImage cropImage(UIImage srcImage, RectangleF rect) { 
    using (CGImage cr = srcImage.CGImage.WithImageInRect (rect)) {
        UIImage cropped = UIImage.FromImage (cr);
        return cropped;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Jason I have seen examples using this method. but then how do i get the rect? the actural cropping is not a problem for me. its getting the scaled rect for the portion of the photo i want. the photos extend beyond the size of the screen.

Comment: can i translate the scrollview content rect or something?

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this by using BeginImageContext using the bounds of the Scrollview,
then rendering in context.